# Unable to the presence of navigation drawer in ActionBar

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

In my android project, the min API level is 11.
Based on Android's guidelines, I need to have an indicator to show the presence of a sliding menu. I added the following lines of code to my MainActivity:

```
drawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this,                  /* host Activity */
                drawerLayout,         /* DrawerLayout object */
                R.drawable.ic_drawer,  /* nav drawer icon to replace 'Up' caret */
                R.string.drawer_open,  /* "open drawer" description */
                R.string.drawer_close  /* "close drawer" description */
                );
         // Set the drawer toggle as the DrawerListener
        drawerLayout.setDrawerListener(drawerToggle);
        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

But still, I do not see the 3 lines on the top that indicate the presence of a sliding menu. What have I done wrong???

*Yes, I do have the icons in drawable folders*

Comment: Are you calling through to `onConfigurationChanged()` and `onOptionsItemSelected()`, and calling `syncState()` from `onPostCreate()`, as is described in the documentation for `ActionBarDrawerToggle`?

Comment: @CommonsWare Ouch! Nope!!